# What kind of user is this?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, down-votes

I found https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community user at stackoverflow today, but not getting what kind of user is this, is it from StackOverflow or its a fake account which is only made to cast downvotes (`12654 downvotes`).

The userid in the URL is -1 :)

Is it from Stackoverflow team or its a fake account, if so can't we block such type of users who just made to make downvotes.

Comment: *waves hand* This is not the user you're looking for.

Comment: FAQ: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tells you right in the gray box on the user page:

> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>
> I'm a background process that helps
>   keep Stack Overflow clean!
>
> I do things like
>
> - Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some
>     attention
> - Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary
>     reputation from them
> - Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted

And now for the misinformative answer!:

> This is an evil and manipulative ploy
>   of the site's creators to
>   pseudorandomly keep people's
>   reputations in check so they don't
>   "lose interest" in the site ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Community is the automated user account that performs many of the system functions.

Comment: But 12654 downvotes, Is it fine to cast downvotes automatically?

Comment: It is casting down votes automatically when you flag items as Spam or Offensive.

Comment: It is not actually casting the down-votes.  What it does is takes the down-votes that other people have cast on spam/offensive questions as its own, so the original down-voter doesn't lose rep.

Comment: Where do the 184 upvotes come from?  They can't be CW posts, there are single questions and answers that have more votes than this.