# why is an old question active?

Tags: support, recent-activity

I'm wondering why [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/63798/hp-pavilion-laptop-mapping-the-remote-control) is shown as active ("1h ago") on the superuser.com start page. I can see nothing that would explain it to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's been bumped by the [Community user](https://superuser.com/users/-1) who occasionally grabs an unanswered question (or even more) and shoves it front and centre to the top of the activity queue.

It helps get the old questions seen by new and/or different people who may have missed them the first time around.

Comment: Random beat me....

Comment: Why does it always seem that these resuscitated questions would have much better been left for dead?

Comment: @Neil Because it is a random question selection. And who better to answer this question then random himself.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Random said (which is correct):

Also see a question asking about who the Community user is: [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)

Which is from the super awesome FAQ: [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq)