# serendipity: occasionally draw attention to random low-scored questions/answers to rescue them from obscurity?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

Some questions seem to be strange attractors.  They get linked to once or twice, which means they are ranked higher in search results, which means that people will see them... which means that they get seen and linked to by more people, ad infinitum.  Success breeds success.

That's fine, and some of these attractors are well deserving of this attention.  However, a potentially better answer to a similar question might languish in obscurity because it didn't happen to get linked from a well-read blog or twitter stream.

It would be great to have a feature where occasionally a random question and answer were presented/suggested to a user with an interest in a keyword associated with that question, suggesting that they vote either up or down on that question.  In addition to giving the asker/answerer some potentially deserved reputation, this might also serve as a pleasant "did you know..." feature for people looking to learn more about a topic.

Comment: Please see: [Why is an old question active?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36823/why-is-an-old-question-active/)

Answer (score 3):

> serendipity = [Community User](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm suggesting; links to old questions are presented to me all the time, in various contexts.  What I am looking for is an explicit suggestion, "please look at this and vote", not just an increased chance that something might get clicked on.

Comment: @Glyph, the 'interesting' question tab does just that, it factors in tags that you might be interested in, and occasionally puts old questions in those tags right up front.