# Question is marked as active, but nothing changed, not bumped by Community

Tags: discussion, bump

On the [active tab of the spring.net tag on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring.net?sort=active&pagesize=50), is shows that [Spring.net vs Application Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395458/spring-net-vs-application-architecture) was changed [by this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1064834/deibyu); however, there are no changes visible in questions or answers, nor is there any activity for this user.

It wasn't bumped by the Community user, so I guess [why is an old question active?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36823/why-is-an-old-question-active) doesn't apply here.

How could this be? Are there other, secret, Community users or something? I am just curious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user [posted an answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRElV.jpg), which was deleted by a moderator. I guess it's a bit frustrating that deleted-activites are still taken into account.

Comment: Ah that's clear then. Interesting to see that a deleted answer still bumps the question.

Comment: @Marijn, I wonder if *the deletion* also bumps it (again). But surely *the posting* of the answer will have bumped it.