# Why is "latest activity" = today on some questions when all the activity happened months ago?

Tags: support, recent-activity

I've noticed that when I scroll through the "Questions" for Superuser.com that sometimes questions show up as "recent" when from my perspective they are any but recent.

By that I mean I look at the date for the question, the answers, and the comments, and all of them are months ago. Yet the summary `latest activity` for the question will have the status `today`.

Here's a link to one example: [Disable internal display on Macbook Pro without closed lid mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/82282/disable-internal-display-on-macbook-pro-without-closed-lid-mode) Perhaps I'm just overlooking the latest activity in which case please just show me where I went wrong. But I didn't see anything newer than Dec 2009.

What's up with this? Because this happens I've found myself wasting time trying to answer questions that no one probably gives a fig about any longer because so much time has passed.

Comment: Newest activity I can see is 24th Jan, you're right though it does say "today".  Pure speculation, but maybe flags affect latest activity and someone flagged it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clicking the entry for "latest activity" will always navigate you straight to when that last activity was.

If the last activity brings you to the question post, and yet the question hasn't been edited (or silently converted to CW), then one scenario is a deletion or activity inside of a deleted post. Without being 10k, you can't see the deleted post, so it instead brings you to the top.

Also, if the Community User bumps a question, this would also cause "latest activity" as the current date, yet direct you at the question post. But you can only confirm this if you can see the question on the front page, by manually locating it through surfing the Active sort of the Questions page, or if you're a 10k user who isn't directed to the deleted post.

The example you linked was in fact bumped by the Community User. The timestamp on the bump is `2010-06-26 21:00:04Z`, which matches the timestamp for the "latest activity".

[image: Image of a post from the front page with a Community signature, that was bumped]

Comment: OK, I guess. It's sort of confusing, but I'll accept it if that's how it works. This does leave me with one question though. What/who is the "Community User"? This is the first time I've encountered the term.

Comment: @irrationalJohn http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user