# Questions with no apparent recent activity show up in "Top Questions" list

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, recent-activity, community-user

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)

The following question is showing up in the front page "Top Questions" list now (2010/10/08 @ 14:55 EDT) as

> 0
>   votes
>   1
>   answer
>   24
>   views
>   How to change iframe inner text ?
>   .net bot 14m ago Community♦ 1

But looking at the question page ([How to change iframe inner text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332513/how-to-change-iframe-inner-text)), there is no apparent recent activity. The question was posted on 2010/07/26 (it has no edits), and the one answer was posted on the same day (it also has no edits).

This appears to be pure noise that should not be showing up on the "Top Questions" display.

Comment: Community wiki picks questions and randomly puts them on the top page in the hopes that low-view questions will get some additional hits and maybe even some answers. `[Status-bydesign]`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community:

> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>
> I'm a background process that helps
>   keep Stack Overflow clean!
>
> I do things like
>
> ```
> * Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some
> ```
>
> attention
>       * Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary
>   reputation from them
>       * Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted

It was poked by community to get some attention.