# Suggest edit is approved when a question is closing as "Possible Duplicates"

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, suggested-edits

I think the pending edit and closed as "Possible Duplicate" should not exist in the same question. The reason is following case:

1. Someone start a "Possible Duplicates" close voting in a question.
   According to the Stack Overflow's rule, this is equal to suggest
   edit the question; we can call it "Pending Version A."
2. Another one edits the question, and a new pending version will be
   appeared. We can call it "Pending Version B."
3. Then the close voting and "Pending Version A" are approved, and the question
   will be added a description, like this:

   > **Possible Duplicate:**
   >   [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)
4. The last, "Pending Version B" is approved, and "Version A" is replaced by
   "Version B"; the "Possible Duplicates" info disappear, and the
   closing as "Possible Duplicates" is invalid.

How does Stack Overflow deal with this situation?

Comment: There's no suggested edit involved here. The Community user has full editing privileges. No one has to approve it, and it's not "pending".

Comment: @Cody Gray I think you didn't understand my case. The case is nothing to do with Community user. I mean the users whose rep is 2000- to edit the question that is closing as "Possible Duplicate".

Answer (score 2):

On the questions closed as a duplicate which I've encountered -- *lacking the 'Possible Duplicates' info* -- I simply:

1. Go into the revision history.
2. Grab the source for the duplicate block.
3. Add it back to the revised version of the question.

There is a possible fourth step where I would consider voting to re-open if the edits specifically differentiate this question from its possible duplicates.  However, I have yet to encounter a situation where I wanted to re-open a question which was closed as a duplicate.

Comment: This is my proposal too.

Comment: But the proposal isn't the best one, because the duplicate block also needs edit.

Comment: The back end could also force the last close voter to clear the suggested edit queue before casting the vote.  However, I think perhaps a better solution would be to place the 'Possible Duplicates' block within a field which **is not** user editable.  I'm tired of watching newbies delete this info because their 'well-formed question' was *closed*.

Comment: Perhaps then only 20K / trusted users can edit the 'Possible Duplicate' (while the rest of us can continue flagging the question as a duplicate of *other questions* which would be auto-appended to the 'Possible Duplicate' section.

Comment: The users who have the privilege to close a question can be given the privilege to edit the 'Possible Duplicate'.

Answer (score 1):

To deal with the issue, I think the best way is the following:

1. Separate the 'Possible Duplicates' info from the question.
2. Allow the users who have closing privilege to edit the 'Possible Duplicates' info.
3. Set 'Possible Duplicates' info edit mode as suggest edit, and the 10k users can approve it.