# How do I hide questions that are bumped by the Community user?

Tags: support, community-user, bump

I am not interested in questions bumped by the Community user. Often times, they are too old to be answered, or already have correct but unaccepted answers.

How do I hide questions bumped by this Community user?

Comment: Just filter the questions via the 'newest' button..? Assuming you have a tag selected..

Comment: @JoshC Even the newest filter will show questions being bumped by Community user.

Comment: @geff_chang The newest tab only shows recently asked questions, so it would never show a question bumped by Community. You'd only see those in the active tabs.

Answer (score 5):

> How do I hide questions bumped by this Community user?

I don't know how you can do this, but at least I can address your concerns about the questions that get bumped.

The [Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) only bumps old questions that have no upvoted answers.

- There's no such thing as "too old to be answered" here. SE sites have a [necromancer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) badge to encourage you to give good answers to old questions. Go ahead and answer them if you want to.

  Unlike, say, a forum, questions here are timeless, new answers are always OK, and "necroing" is not a bad thing - you get a silver badge for it!
- If they have correct but unaccepted answers, the question was bumped because none of those answers were upvoted. If you're confident a bumped answer was correct, upvote it. This is the sort of positive outcome the bumping exists for, so go ahead and do it! That question won't get bumped anymore.