# Protected Questions - Is this feature used and is it still useful in Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, protected-questions

That is an issue that I wonder. I know `Question Protection` do not allow users below 10 *local reputation (earned on related site)* to answer. That sounds logical since there could be questions that attracts users more that the other ones.

But, on the other hand, Stack Overflow is really crowded now. Maybe 10.000 (just a guess) questions received daily and there is quite a lot of active users to *flag* or *vote for deletion* for a spam or unwanted-style answer.

Also I rarely come across `protected questions`. [What is a “protected” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52764/173052) states:

> Some questions are protected because they are expected to attract either spam or users -- often new users -- who may mistake the site as a traditional forum, posting "noisy" answers such as "Thank you" or "This worked for me" or "I'm also having this problem".

Also, considering *How and by whom a Question can become Protected*:

> - Diamond moderators
> - Users with at least 15,000 reputation, with the following restrictions:
>
>   - The question must be at least a day old
>   - A user can un-protect a question protected by him or herself, but not one that has been protected by someone else
> - The system (via the Community user) will automatically protect a question that's had three answers from low-rep users deleted.

If I consider Stack Overflow, *user attraction* can be handed better if a post receives high view count in a defined timespan. *Spams* are handled by active users (as I tell).

Thinking about the above quotation from the *What is a “protected” question?* and density of quite low protected questions (that statement is based on my time spent on SO, if there are more protected questions then I saw, you can told me that claim is wrong), I just wonder: ***Question Protection is still useful in a site with high-traffic and a lot of active users?***

Also questions having:

- high view count in a defined time interval
- At least one deleted answer flagged as *spam/not an answer(thank you, me to type answers)*

should be auto-protected by [community-user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)? My guess is no, because that may also prevent new users if above limits do not set properly (But wish to ask and take your ideas about that topic too.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question protection is definitely useful and I think the auto-protection rules have it about right.

Mostly this is useful for questions that somehow becomes "spam magnets", but is otherwise ok. I *think* it's usually bots that latch on to a question because of a keyword or two and repeatedly try to post the same or similar spammy answers. There are some questions which just seem to keep attracting spam like this until they get protected.

In short it definitely works for the cases where it's most appropriate.

The fact that it's rare suggests to me that we've got the balance right. It is unfortunate that it stops new users potentially posting better answers (but it's not particularly hard to get 10 rep in other ways if it really is a blocker).

Sometimes (particularly during Facebook/Paypal API outages) a particular questions gets a lot of google-fu and suddenly becomes a dumping ground for "I have this too" "answers". Again it's rare, which is what we want, but it works and the penalty is tolerable.

In my view the automatic triggering and privilege is important for two reasons:

1. In the flag queue it isn't always obvious that there's a pattern, so we don't even have to look at it, manually identify the pattern and then act.
2. It makes the whole process not dependent on moderators actions, it's something the community can do alone which makes it scalable.

I think we've got the balance about right for triggering. A single spam/NAA shouldn't be sufficient to trigger it because you simply can't infer a pattern from one data point alone and protection is about handling patterns not just isolated incidents. (There's an English idiom that's quite appropraite [*"One swallow does not a summer make"*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/one_swallow_does_not_a_summer_make))

Finally, as it stands this is an effective protection mechanism that's entirely transparent - that's great because it fixes the problem and educates at the same time without relying on secrect voodoo sauce or bad UX.

Comment: 10k example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477852/wordpress-administrator-error-save-post-with-a-domain-idnseo

Comment: Or: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623582/facebook-like-count-for-articles-reset-to-zero which was protected pre-close.