# In exactly what circumstances can a question be deleted by Community?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions, community-user

Questions can be deleted [for a variety of reasons, and by a variety of agents](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that), notably including moderators, 10k+ users, and automatic processes in the server. In most cases, the deletion notice makes it fairly clear to attribute which of those agents actually deleted the question.

However, it seems that there are some cases that bend this rule. In particular, [this question in Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/187569) (discussed [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6843/concern-about-question-deletion-science-can-look-after-itself-and-repudiate-of) on meta) was deleted by a moderator, apparently acting on a flag, but appears to 10k+ users as deleted by [Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user).

So, for clarity:

#### Under what circumstances will a question deletion notice attribute the deletion to the Community user?

Furthermore, if the deletion was acted on by a moderator, is there any way to audit this fact?

Answer (score 9):

- Spam/offensive flags delete posts with attribution to the community user. It does not matter if regular users or a moderator casts the flag(s)
- account destruction by a moderator does this as well
- [older questions with low scores and no upvoted answers are removed automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/151385)
- negatively-scored posts are removed when a user is deleted
- on Area 51 Discussions only, questions about specific proposals are deleted if the proposal in question is deleted

There is no direct way for regular users to find out exactly who performed the action that lead to removal of such posts. That generally doesn't matter all that much as most of these actions are on blatant spam or offensive posts.

But you can of course initiate a review of this action by either posting on your meta, or contacting SE (via the "contact us" link in the footer). Moderators and SE employees can find out who removed the post.

Comment: @MichaelT I knew I was missing a few, I just couldn't remember the other reasons

Comment: Just to clarify, this is still the case independently of whether it's six independent flags causing automated deletion vs a single flag confirmed by a moderator?

Comment: @E.P. Yes, you can't distinguish this from the publicly visible information.

Comment: Also, if a post is deleted from the low-quality review queue via "recommend deletion" votes, that deletion is either attributed to Community or just not attributed (don't remember which; don't have an example handy).  The timeline for the post shows who the voters were.

Comment: @MonicaCellio On the question page, one simply sees "deleted [some time ago]", with no indication of by whom. On the Revision History of the post (`/posts/{id}/revisions/`) the event is shown as "Post Deleted From Review",  which links to the review page listing the reviewers.