# Why was this discussion on Area 51 deleted by Community♦?

Tags: support, area-51, community-user

I thought I was going crazy searching for [this discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20457/overlap-with-blender/20460) until I found I wasn't the only one who remembered it existing.

Here's an [archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150907104202/https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20457/overlap-with-blender/20460), and a screenshot of how the page currently appears to me:

[image]

Why did the Community♦ bot delete it?

It's a valuable discussion on an active proposal.
After it disappeared, users started asking the [same questions](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25261/relationship-with-blender-stackexchange-if-successful) all over again..

---

After reading [Shadow Wizard's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284557/238438), I have more questions about the system and whether it should be more forgiving. I've posted a followup [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) report [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284560/238438).

Comment: This is especially egregious because there was a previous, very similar proposal from six years ago, now compounded with one just a year old. So, as the OP mentions, many of a going in circles trying to find the pertinent discussion materials for review in the pending proposal. Sorry, but this one seems like a fairly big SE boo boo.

Comment: How do you know that it was deleted by Community? All I can see at that link is "This question was removed from Area 51 Discussions for reasons of moderation."

Comment: @Gothdo Ah, it looks different to me (as the OP I guess). Added a screenshot

Comment: @HowardPautz See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738/238438

Comment: Also, if someone decides this behavior should be kept, please leave some kind of notice so poor Cow's and other users don't start thinking their loosing their minds.

Comment: thx gandalf3 - yes, now that you've posted the archive screenshot, there's no question "who" deleted the post... the real question is - in this context - *why*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **As mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284585/152859), this has been fixed at some point after this specific incident**

---

In the question, you linked to [CAD proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80927/computer-aided-design-cad).

This caused a link to be created behind the scenes between your question and that proposal.

When that proposal was deleted (due to inactivity probably), all questions linked to it have been removed. Your question is innocent victim.

You should flag the question and ask to undelete it.

Comment: How do these magic links work then? I linked to 3D graphics first. Does it only pay attention to the last link? Or does it take all links into account? How does that work?

Comment: @gandalf3 I'm not 100% sure, but I think all links are taken. For example on ordinary sites (like this) all  those links [are shown in the sidebar](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TPdRx.png), in Area 51 each proposal is actually a post behind the scenes, e.g. it [even got revisions page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/posts/86368/revisions) - so when you link to proposals, it's like linking to questions here. This might even take links posted as comments and in answers.