# Misunderstood Area 51 discussions prone to sudden and silent deletion

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

A [discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20457/overlap-with-blender/20460) I started on Area 51 [was mysteriously wiped out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284556/238438), apparently [because it contained a link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284557/238438) pointing to a [now-deleted proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80927/computer-aided-design-cad).

Admittedly, the link to the deleted proposal was included by mistake, however, it seems alarming to me that relatively large discussions attached to a [currently active proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-graphics-modeling-animation) can be automatically deleted without warning in this manner.

How exactly does Community♦ choose its next victim on Area51?
How does the logic relating discussions to proposals through links work?

Can this system be adjusted to be more forgiving of stray links?  Mistakes happen when your users are fleshy accident-prone earthlings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has already been fixed.

Discussions are no longer removed unless ALL of the proposals it linked to have been deleted.

The **original** logic assumed if the discussion linked to *multiple* proposals, it was either a discussion about duplicates or a merger. In the older system, if all the proposal were deleted except one, it was assumed the discussion was either moot or has already been resolved (i.e. one proposal survives).

Area 51 no longer works this way. Discussion for active proposals are no longer removed.

Comment: So what caused the discussion [mentioned here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284556/why-was-this-discussion-on-area-51-deleted-by-community?noredirect=1&lq=1) to be auto deleted?

Comment: @ShadowWizard The original discussion linked to a proposal which was deleted.

Comment: So the fix was put in place after January this year, when that discussion was deleted?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I'm still missing a tonne of posts, and they are quite tricky to find. Could something be done to restore the old posts?

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Which posts are you looking for? I don't want to undelete old posts when the proposals are long gone, but I can pull  up something specific and send you the contents by email.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I'll look and see (I don't need any right now). I thought maybe sort of an Anti-script could be used to undelete all community deleted proposals (with a positive score) that link to a still active proposal. Its also even harder to track down missing posts that one didn't ask or answer.