# Question migration problem

Tags: feature-request, support, migration, moderators

Recently [I asked](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2507/community-user-spam-detection-failure) about Community user robot bug.

I think this it was an important question about bug that make really bad feeling during whole StackExchange using and not partial StackExchange community. Such a source of bad user experience should be taken to consideration of whole community not a single one.

The question is why was it migrated? I want to ask to move it back to generic questions Meta if it made by generic bot. If not than I want to make it new feature request. Such actions should be visible. If it was made by group of moderators than why show bot name? Show the members.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who is the Community user?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)

Comment: I must be missing something here. How can a question that is asking to undo a migration be a dupe of a question asking what/who is the community user?? One may disagree with the request or close it if he thinks (probably correctly) that this is not the way to ask for the migration to be undone... but still doesn't seem a dupe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question wasn't migrated by a robot, it was [migrated by an SE employee](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/285791/revisions).

Also, your post on that site was destroyed as spam via a moderator spam flag or a series of spam flags from community members. "Community" is the identifier applied to such an action, but there is no robot that automatically deletes spam on these sites. Those actions are carried out by humans, and can be site-specific.

Moderators on that site [have explained why people thought it was spam](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2509/24863). This isn't a network-wide bug, it's a site-specific moderation issue, thus the migration.

Comment: I think this should be visible as made by member list, not "Community" then.

Answer (score 7):

You were asking about why your specific question was closed and deleted.  That's a community specific question.  Members of another community wouldn't be in a good position to comment on the merits of your particular question.

Comment: Yes, but it was closed by "Community" bot. This controlling bot is all stacks user.

Comment: @Sergei And the appropriate place to ask why your question was deleted by "Community" is on that site's meta.

Comment: If it was deleted by group of members then this should be publicly available information not hidden by "Community" bot name.

Comment: @Sergei You're welcome to discuss that on that site's meta, if you would like.