# Why was the Community/Moderator hammer used on this question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, moderation

So there's this question [How to stop Visual Studio (2019) from adding line on the end of file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59735414/how-to-stop-visual-studio-2019-from-adding-line-on-the-end-of-file), which clearly had some problems, but with patience and effort I was able to work through it in the comments with this relatively new SO user and get their question to the state that it could be answered.

And then a moderator closed it with one vote.

There already was one vote to close made before I was able to explain to the OP why we needed additional information from them, so that seemed reasonable.  However, whoever used the mod hammer to close it (it's hidden behind the Community account, so I don't know who it is)  did so *after* the OP had edited the question to an acceptable state, so it just seems vindictive.

And now, after doing the work to get them to the point of understanding and adding the necessary information, and then doing the work to be able to answer the question, as I was entering my answer, the question was Closed ("no more answers can be added").  So now, at best, I have to go through the process of hoping that 4 other contributors will notice and vote to reopen.

I can understand why new users are hard to work with sometimes.  I really cannot understand why after well over a decade, SO is still doing stuff like this.  So why is that?

---

Ok so,:

> When it's done by the Community user, it is always the author of the
>   question that clicked the button to confirm the other question
>   resolved their problem

Ah, right. I did not know this, my bad.  I would like to delete this question now, but it was fairly answered and they deserve the points.  Plus I am probably not the only person to not realize that "closed by Community*" means that it was closed by the OP, so I will leave it for posterity.

Comment: When “Community” shows up in the closer voters list, it means OP voted to close as a duplicate himself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)

Comment: You agreed that this question is a duplicate.

Comment: @MulliganReinstatingMonica No I did not.  It is not as far as I can tell a duplicate. As the OP explained, VSCode is different from Visual Studio and has different settings.

Comment: @RBarryYoung None the less, OP agreed with the duplicate closure.

Comment: Self-marking questions as duplicates are binding. Also, this question is liable to downvotes as it is not too useful in the long run; it seems too localized.

Comment: The other question has this answer at the end of a very long list of things.  I'd rather take my medicine (and the downvotes) here, for the sake of others who may not know.

Comment: You don't get points for closing a question. Only having your edits accepted, earning bounties, receiving upvotes on a question, and receiving upvotes on an answer give you reputation. You can delete it if you wish.

Comment: Why was this closed  as off-topic? It might or might not be a duplicate, but I do not see how it is off-topic...

Comment: @wimi I accidentally posted it in the wrong meta.  Should have been in meta.SO, not meta.SE.

Comment: @wimi Questions that only pertain to situations on one specific site are marked "off-topic" here. There is a specific reason shown to the author and users with enough rep to vote to close, but since you don't have enough reputation, you can't see it. (I personally don't like this model, but...)

Comment: @RBarryYoung Here on Meta Stack Exchange, we close questions as duplicates of questions tagged [tag:faq] if the answer to that question also addresses this question, even though the questions themselves may not be exactly the same. This is to link users to the canonical posts regarding topics. See [this section of our FAQ on how Meta Stack Exchange works](/a/47635/377214) and the last section of [our FAQ on duplicate closures](/a/10844/377214).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When it's done by the Community user, it is always the author of the question that clicked the button to confirm the other question resolved their problem. No other user can invoke the Community user to close as duplicate.

Also, on Stack Overflow, it only takes three users to close and reopen questions now.

Comment: To be exact: when you hover over Community in the edit history it tells you "This question's author approved a pending duplicate vote."