# Community bot's question labeled with incorrect user - or vice versa

Tags: discussion, questions, community-user

As per this screenshot, from the Home page:
[image]

It says that the Community bot asked that question.  But why does it say, when you visit the question, from this screenshot:

[image]

That it was asked by user825151?  And that, when you hover over the username, it doesn't take you to the profile page?  Shouldn't it say Community?  The community bot didn't ask a question, then delete its account, did it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User was deleted, and [deleted user's posts, votes and other things are attributed to community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739/135565).

It’s by design.